# Flash .fla embed banner add

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to create a Flash web banner. The .swf file size needs to be >40k so I made a .fla video and tried to stream it into the file however I'm getting no luck.

I can't find anything on the internet so I thought I'd ask here.

Im using Flash CC AS3
When I run the file through the 
https://flashval-temp.appspot.com/validator/

the .swf uploads but the .fla doesn't play at all.

The code I was using was:

```
var vid:Video;
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
var customClient:Object = new Object();
customClient.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
ns.client = customClient;
ns.play("300x250.flv");

vid = new Video();
vid.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(vid);

function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
{
    trace(event.text);
}

function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
    vid.width = infoObject.width;
    vid.height = infoObject.height;
}
```

It seems to work fine offline, the files are in the same directory too.

Comment: Is the ad being served through a platform like MediaMind or DoubleClick?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full environment it's hard to tell you what's wrong, but you may want to check these:

(1) upload your video file to a server and grab the full url to the file, then update your code with it:

```
ns.play("http://www.YOUR_DOMAIN.com/300x250.flv");
```

(2) add the following as3:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

(3) If that still doesn t work, look into crossdomain.xml at the root of your server hosting the video.

But (1) is likely to be the issue.